# Mypy shows error for pyspark replace function

Tags: python, pyspark, mypy, type-hinting

Mypy shows error for `pyspark` `replace` function.

`main.py`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName(__name__).getOrCreate()
x = {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
df = spark.read.parquet('abc')
df.replace(x, subset=df.columns)
```

Error message:

```
$ mypy main.py
main.py:7: error: Argument 1 to "replace" of "DataFrame" has incompatible type "dict[str, str]"; expected "dict[bool | float | int | str, bool | float | int | str | None]"  [arg-type]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's likely a deficiency in their stubs, they should've used `Mapping` instead of `dict` for value variance, with `Any` as key type to prevent issues like this. You can pass `subset=` inline (without temporary `x`), annotate `x` as they ask you to (that monstrous `dict[...]`), or do `df.replace(dict(x), subset=df.columns)` - the last one is a common trick to cast a dictionary with narrower type to the type required by external function, it works, because such dict is not usable by you afterwards.